# How do I reverse a sentence in C?

Tags: c

In this program, I'm trying to input a sentence and print the sentence in reverse order. Like for example, if my input is "I Like You", then my output must be "You Like I". Please help me fix this code!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void words(char arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
       if(arr[i]==' ')
       {
           arr[i]='\0';
           printf("%s ", &(arr[i])+1);
       }
    }
    printf("%s", arr);
}

int main()
{
    char x[50];
    printf("Enter the sentence: ");
    gets(x);

    int size=strlen(x);

    void words(x, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) dont use `gets()`: it is dangerous because it doesn't provide any control capability on the size of data received in input, possibly causing crashes. 2) For your task you might find useful checking out [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Comment: Are you trying to actually *sort* the words, or just print them in reverse order?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove void form line 22 change `void words(x, size);` to `words(x, size);`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void words(char arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
       if(arr[i]==' ')
       {
           arr[i]='\0';
           printf("%s ", &(arr[i])+1);
       }
    }
    printf("%s", arr);
}

int main()
{
    char x[50];
    printf("Enter the sentence: ");
    //gets(x);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",x);

    int size=strlen(x);

    words(x, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the sentence: i like you                                                                                        
you like i
```

Note: You should not use `gets()` due to some security reasons. For reference why not use `gets()`? visit this:

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: @caden If this answer helps you Please accept by tick (✓) mark so that other people will also get help from this.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni yes you are right i am removing `gets()`

Comment: @Sheri Nice job.